# terraform plan error : Argument not expected here

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create custom IAM roles for different environments, with different set of permissions for dev and prod, in Google Cloud Platform. My folder structure is as follows:

**iamroles** (root folder)
-- main.tf
-- variables.tf
--**customiamroles**(folder)
----main.tf
--**environments**
----**nonprod**
------main.tf
------variables.tf
----**prod**
------main.tf
------variables.tf

The main.tf in the root folder has the below code:

**iamroles/main.tf**

```
    /*
          This is the 'main' Terraform file. It calls the child modules to create roles in the corresponding environments
    */

    provider "google" {
     credentials = file("${var.project_id}.json")
     project     = var.project_id
     region      = var.location
    }

    module "nonprod" {
      source = "./environments/nonprod"
    }
```

**iamroles/variables.tf**

```
    variable "project_id"{
        type = string
    }

    variable "location" {
        type = string
        default = "europe-west3"
    }
```

**iamroles/environments/nonprod/main.tf**

```
module "nonprod" {  
  role_details = [{
        role_id = "VS_DEV_NONPROD_CLOUDSQL",
        title       = "VS DEVELOPER NON PROD CLOUD SQL",
        description = "Role which provides limited view and update access to Cloud SQL",
        permissions = var.developer_nonprod_sql
    },
    {
        role_id = "VS_DEV_NONPROD_APPENGINE",
        title       = "VS DEVELOPER NON PROD APPENGINE",
        description = "Appengine access for developers for non production environments to View, Create and Delete versions, View and Delete instances, View and Run cron jobs",
        permissions = var.developer_nonprod_appengine
    }]
    source = "../../customiamroles"
}
```

**iamroles/environments/nonprod/variables.tf**

```
    variable "role_details" {
        type = list(object({
        role_id = string
        title = string
        description = string
        permissions = list(string)
      }))
    }

    variable "developer_nonprod_sql" {
        default = ["cloudsql.databases.create","cloudsql.databases.get"]
    }

    variable "developer_nonprod_appengine" {
        default = ["appengine.applications.get","appengine.instances.get","appengine.instances.list","appengine.operations.*","appengine.services.get","appengine.services.list"]
    }
```

**iamroles/customiamroles/main.tf**

```
# Creating custom roles
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "vs-custom-roles" {
  for_each = var.role_details
  role_id     = each.value.role_id
  title       = each.value.title
  description = each.value.description
  permissions = each.value.permissions
}
```

While executing terraform plan from iamroles folder, i am getting the below exception:
[image]

I am new to terraform, learning for the past two days. I could use some help to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The module `customiamroles` does not have a `variables.tf` file or any defined variables.

Comment: I added the variables.tf file in customiamroles folder and added the variable role_details. I re-executed the terraform plan. Getting the below error:Error: Missing required argument

  on main.tf line 11, in module "nonprod":
  11: module "nonprod" {

The argument "role_details" is required, but no definition was found.

Comment: yes, that is totally correct, you have a `iamroles/environments/nonprod/variables.tf` but do not specify any variable values inside `iamroles/main.tf` when using that module.

Comment: So am i supposed to add the role_details variable to iamroles/variables.tf file instead of keeping it in iamroles/environment/nonprod/variables.tf file? In this case, will it not ask for an input while executing? because the role_details is a list of objects which varies for nonprod and prod. How do I dynamically allocate the roles for each environment?